# own legend and show/hide series echarts

Tags: events, legend, echarts

I prepare my own legend with checkboxes for echarts. When a checkbox is clicked, it invokes a special function to remove data from the chart. I remove or add this data from series and reload chart.

However eCharts has own legend with events like legendToggleSelect and select etc. Maybe can I use some functions or maybe dispatchAction to show/hide data instead of add/removing?

I try to use dispatchAction, but it doesnt show/hide, it only start animations.

I use dispatchAction like that:

```
myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: "legendToggleSelect",
    name: id,

});
```

But in only start animations, not hide/show series.

Comment: If you want to use the echarts legend or your on depends on the data. The echarts [legend data](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#legend.data) is filled with the [name](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.name) of your series and comes with the toggle function by default (see [this exmaple](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-y-category)). You would need to share your code for a more specific answer.

Comment: Yes, I have unique name for my series. dispatchAction only do animation, not hide or show my series. I add code of dispatchAction in the main thread.

Comment: Here is your [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsA2BTA5l6AJgFzIC-ANGrAB4CC1EAziauumAJ4hYkDkAxgEMwuYACcOvSm1gFhgkgG1eAWRhTYvACoBXLBt4B1LAQNaAFjoMAxMRAMBlYY53ReAXSoUqHekxZU7Fw8mgBughh6vF7SsIxYdljMsIqByGlB3HwARoJiUhmw0IIAtiG8JRwAcqX6sTJyYAopAIwATAAM5LCdXbAtAKx9ABx9AOx9LS2TAMwd7vWwpFSepADcQA) using the echarts legend.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I have given example to dispatchAction to show/hide series.

[EXAMPLE](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-y-category&code=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-dWu1BI05dQPtRQPNnUaZlVjgEgudwhEIrrVWdGkiFDm9ZpDWKIgAOcJAlIhIGw8sAThrDbCdZSETCsIbAHYJSQIkCIt3YbCUgA2IFhWthaPGWPGFPGNN5zMhIuzU5NAvydf60uiiINoEhVI1utA8spQcZPtRCKpBuj_t1iKwiLj8sVsLd2cxxG_VNAhXSIgXXZk823XcSyNMdK1bGsx3rJs0hbNt-07HtbyBIFhyfSdp1_Eh52oRd_CAppM1hMDN3OSD_2LA0jUPbDTxIWtYRCS8SGvMJTzvVJEPbF833HMcvx_GZHmoOVYgSIA)

```
myChart.dispatchAction({
  type: "legendToggleSelect",
  name:"SERIES_NAME"
});
```

NOTE: Use below example if you have your own/custom legend list instead of echarts list.

[FULL EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/abhaypadamani/pen/VwRJJvR)

Comment: Can legendselectchanged hide one series and show the others?

Comment: You can create your own logic. In the parameters, you will have a key named `selected` which is an array. Each series will have a Boolean flag indicating whether to hide or show the series. You can develop your own logic to determine which series you want to show or hide.

Comment: @kweronika i have updated my solution can you check whether your requirement fulfills?

Comment: I think you dont understad me. I have my own legend, not legend from echarts. In this legend I have checkbox which void function and this function should show/hide the series on the chart. And I dont know how to do it, how to show/hide series.

Comment: Okay, understood. If you provide a sample example using a  CodePen link, feel free to share the link with me, and I can take a look at it for you.

Comment: https://codepen.io/kweronika/pen/GRebzmw
can you open it?

Comment: Ohh, got the issue. [https://codepen.io/abhaypadamani/pen/VwRJJvR](https://codepen.io/abhaypadamani/pen/VwRJJvR)

here, you just need to add below code in your option

`legend:{
    show:false,
  },`

Comment: Thanks @kweronika. Please upvote to my solution, if you find solution.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation for vote, but If I will have enough I will do it :)